# when in Sequelize I am trying to select columns for both inner joined table some of the joined table columns are nested in alias

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am still new to Sequelize and I am trying to select specific columns from both table in inner join using sequelize. Here is what I have

```
        const paramPostgres: QueryBuilder = {
        raw: false,
        nest: true,
        include: [{
            model: UserAccountDeRepository.getInstance().model, as: "userAccountTableAlias",
            attributes: ["account"],
            required: true
        }],
        attributes: ["is_archived", "status", "udiId"],
        where: {
        '$userAccountTableAlias.user$': usernames
        }
    }
```

as you can see attributes: ["is_archived", "status", "udiId"] gives me the columns I want from main table while attributes: ["account"] gives me the column name I want from joined table. My problem is the following response format:

```
[{"is_archived":false,"status":"COMPLETED","udiId":"9e8350f1-fab0-4861-96ae-1268118c49a3","userAccountTableAlias":{"account":"133b5f93-916b-46c1-b429-6c071c752097"}}]
```

as you can see all columns are back but account from joined model is buried in userAccountTableAlias

what I want to get is the following

```
    [{"is_archived":false,"status":"COMPLETED","udiId":"9e8350f1-fab0-4861-96ae-1268118c49a3","account":"133b5f93-916b-46c1-b429-6c071c752097"}]
```

but not sure how to achieve that. I appreciate any help

Comment: Have you tried to remove the alias or name it `account`?

Comment: but account is a name of a column. I need a way to be able to get the columns from userAccountTableAlias in a way that is not nested

Comment: have you tried **raw: true**, the result will return dotted property. `"userAccountTableAlias.account" :  "133b5f93-916b-46c1-b429-6c071c752097"`